# ABI artifacts corrupted, manually edit ABI?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-debugging, abi

Is it possible to manually add functions to the ABI, specifically the getProduct and addProductToStore functions? Does it make a difference?
Have already tried deleting build + recompiling + remigrating, same issue. Believe it to be an problem with Truffle's build process corrupting the artifacts?

Similar to this issue: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/685

Remix :

```
[
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "productIndex",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_productId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getProduct",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint8"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_category",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_imageLink",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_descLink",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_auctionStartTime",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "_auctionEndTime",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "_startPrice",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "_productCondition",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addProductToStore",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    }
]
```

Local Json file:

```
"abi": [
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "productIndex",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

this issue was said to be fixed many times in the past, but you can definitely get rid of it by downgrading to truffle 3.x, deleting the build/contracts/ folder (but back it up, just in case!) and do `truffle compile --all`.

Besides that, you can of course add all information on functions to the JSON file as you like, it just has to correspond to the solidity code.

Comment: Could you please reference links where issue was supposedly fixed? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1043